# Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Tags: java, junit, windows-7

I packed test classes into JAR. I have `junit-4.10.jar` and `aJar.jar` in the same folder. When I try to execute:

```
java -cp .:junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestOne

Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

How to make it work?

When I type: `java aJar.jar:junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestOne`

I am getting

```
Error: Could not find or load main class aJar.jar:junit-4.10.jar
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be running under Windows, not LINUX/UNIX. The path separator on Windows is `;`, not `:`. Additionally, you haven't put you jar file in the classpath. So what you want is:

```
java -cp aJar.jar;junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestOne
```

This of course assumes that both jars are in the current directory. You should also always avoid putting classes in the default package.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently the same problem (JUnit 4.12) and I managed to solve it (Windows) by the following command:

```
java -cp "<libs>;<relative path to .class project folder>" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <package.ClassName>
```

Import to notice the "" in the classpath declaration and separated by ";"

Comment: `javac -cp "junit-4.12.jar; hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;." Tests.java` worked for me. Note the ending dot - it's important!